# InvalidReportParameterException: Default value or value provided for the report parameter <ParameterName>is not a valid value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

Having some difficulty in passing values to SSAS data source - SSRS report via Data driven subscription, it runs fine when ran manually or scheduled via regular subscription. It fails when tried via data subscription with below error

InvalidReportParameterException: Default value or value provided for the report parameter  is not a valid value.

Already tried several things suggested over the internet
like leading spaces, data types all that stuff still no luck

Comment: We know nothing about the parameter settings for your data driven subscription. What kind of answer do you expect? You will have to try all other stuff you did not yet try. Or update your post and add the details on your parameter setup.

Comment: "All the other stuff you did not try yet" - comedy gold right there ;-)